# Le temps pour décrire des gens morts

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

Quel temps utilise-t-on pour décrire des gens morts ?

Dans le [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Gauguin), il est écrit :

> Paul Gauguin [...] mort le 8 mai 1903, [...] est un peintre
>   postimpressionniste.

Pourquoi présent ?

---

Which tense do you use when describing people that have passed away?

On [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Gauguin), it says:

> Paul Gauguin [...] mort le 8 mai 1903, [...] est un peintre
>   postimpressionniste.

How come they use the present tense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Le présent de l'indicatif s'emploie  :

- pour exprimer une action qui est en train de se dérouler (présent d'actuel) :

> Il pleut.

pour exprimer un fait toujours vrai, (présent permanent) :

> Paul Gauguin est un peintre postimpressionniste.

- c'est la valeur qu'il a dans les proverbes :

> Qui veut voyager loin, ménage sa monture.

pour raconter une histoire ou un récit historique, procédé utilisé par les historiens et les romanciers pour rendre le lecteur témoin direct de l'événement (présent historique) :

> En 1886, Gauguin effectue son premier séjour à Pont-Aven en Bretagne.

pour exprimer une action juste passée :

> Tu as déjà fini ? **Je finis** à l'instant.

pour exprimer une action future :

> Je prends mes vacances en juillet.

pour exprimer un irréel dans une subordonnée après un *si* conditionnel et quand la principale est au futur.

> S'il vend beaucoup de tableau il sera riche.

Answer (score 4):

The [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) is a weird tradition of French history writing. There's really not much more to say about it. You find it in English too, but I believe it is far, far more widespread in French encyclopedic and history prose.

Answer (score 1):

Pour dire qu’une personne est morte, le présent est parfaitement acceptable car il a valeur de [vérité générale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomisme).
Ce présent est utilisé pour des choses qui sont vraies tout le temps, (vérités scientifiques, faits passés et définitifs).